# jQuery fadeIn() of TR clips background

Tags: jquery, css, firefox

If I do a fadeIn() that changes the dimensions of a table, Firefox clips the background of the newly shown rows.

[image: clipped background]

If I click focus away from the tab, and then click back, the background is restored.

[image: proper background]

There is no clipping issue in Chrome.  I'm on Firefox 26

See [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/axiomx11/g5MhM/)

**JS**

```
$(function () {
    $(".small-link").on("click", function (event) {
        $(".showfields").fadeIn(250);
    });
});
```

**CSS**

```
.head {
    background-color: green;
    color:white;
}
.hidden {
    display:none;
}
.small-link {
    cursor:pointer;
}
table {
    border:1px solid red;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><a class="small-link">Click this</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="hidden showfields">
        <td>........................................</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="head hidden showfields">
        <th>Table Head</th>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Notes:

1. Just showing the TR works, but I would like to fade it if I can
2. Fading the TH and TD instead do fix the issue for this simple case, but won't work for my actual code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is a FF bug but you can get around it by using .fadeTo() instead of .fadeIn().

```
$(".showfields").fadeTo(250,.99);
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/g5MhM/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

Apply the background to the `th` element, not to the `tr`:

```
.head th{
    background-color: green;
    color:white;
}
```

[**LIVING DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/g5MhM/2/)

Comment: _"Fading the TH and TD instead do fix the issue for this simple case, but won't work for my actual code"_

Comment: @j08691 I'm not telling him to fade anything. Just to change the CSS background property for the TH, which is the correct way to do it.

Comment: Well my point was really that it seems like the OP doesn't/can't modify the th/td but I could me wrong. Bit vague.